# Parsing firebase object javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

It might be duplicate, sorry for that but I couldn't understand (New to firebase and JS).

I have a **snapshot** from firebase, but I couldn't understand how to parse that snapshot object.

Here is my code:

```
var obj = snapshot.val();
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

It outputs following:

```
{"-KpxDFnJEt2xlD21lzyh":{"chatid":"6qKi8xO5vxdrcKFd5wqUNUkTupg2PNQjC87cFNcKxYkDoYMdhH95LCK2"}}
```

I want to get this `-KpxDFnJEt2xlD21lzyh` value in a separate variable and `chatid` into separate variable, but not be able to.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the key name and its `chatid` value:

```js
var json = {
  "-KpxDFnJEt2xlD21lzyh": {
    "chatid": "6qKi8xO5vxdrcKFd5wqUNUkTupg2PNQjC87cFNcKxYkDoYMdhH95LCK2"
  }
}
for (key in json) {
  if (!json.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
  console.log(key);
  console.log(json[key].chatid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following?

```
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj); i++) {
    console.log(Object.keys(obj)[i]); // -KpxDFnJEt2xlD21lzyh
    console.log(obj[Object.keys(obj)[i]]["chatid"]); // 6qKi8xO5vxdrcKFd5wqUNUkTupg2PNQjC87cFNcKxYkDoYMdhH95LCK2
}
```

That will loop through the JSON object getting each key, printing the key and chat id.

Answer (score 0):

You can access keys in an object `Object.Keys`, it will return an array. At index 0 you will have your first key. Similarly, to access value, you can use `Object.Values`, it will return an array.

```js
var response = {"-KpxDFnJEt2xlD21lzyh":{"chatid":"6qKi8xO5vxdrcKFd5wqUNUkTupg2PNQjC87cFNcKxYkDoYMdhH95LCK2"}};

var id = Object.keys(response);
var chats = Object.values(response);

console.log(id[0]);
console.log(chats[0]['chatid']);
```